# multiple projects with same vendor folder on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have multiple projects with very little space to keep.

since most of them uses nearly same packages (only 1 uses phpexcel and the other one swiftmailer ) and vendor folder required biggest space on laravel.

I thought maybe I could use same vendor folder for every of them.

I actually messed with autoload.php and some other config files however I couldn't make it.

simply I'll put vendor folder under public_html and create folder like project1 project2.
under those folders I'll put everything about my projects except vendor folder and then make them subdomain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't.

**Long answer:**

/vendor folder is not just about packages, you also have in there `vendor/composer` folder, where your application classes names are stored for autoloading purposes. Everytime you run composer dump-autoload, Composer changes the content of some files there. Take a look at the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php file, you'll see that some of those classes are from your own project.

**Workaroud:**

Please note that I don't see a thing like this going well, but you can, actually, create a blank project, just for package downloading and symlink all packages from all your vendors folders to that one. It's a lot of trouble for a little gain. But it's up to you, of course.

Comment: It is not necessary to have Composer autoload classes from my application. I can load my application classes with my custom autoloader and use it parallelly with Composer autoloader (`spl_autoload_register()` allows multiple autoloaders to be registered). Thus it could be possible to use same Composer autoload for multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://www.wenda.io/questions/2416709/laravel-4-1-vendor-directory-config.html

edit composer.json

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "vendor-dir": "../vendor"
},
```

edit bootstrap/autoload.php file

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php'
```

edit bootstrap/start.php file

```
$framework = $app['path.base'].
             '/../vendor/laravel/framework/src';
```

edit ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Optimize/config.php

```
$basePath = $app['path.base'].'/../';
```

then run composer install, you will find vendor dir created ../

```
php artisan optimize -v --force
```

Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes